# Spring MapBindingResult second argument of the constructor meaning

Tags: java, spring

I have the following code

```
 Errors errors = new MapBindingResult(new HashMap(), "person");
```

Why do we specify **"person"** as the second argument, when is it used?

Comment: Similar solution is at -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607491/using-spring-validator-outside-of-the-context-of-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its basically to pinpoint the error context. It tells the client or the end user that the errors are related to which entity , in your case person.

If you will see the default messages that spring will put for validations, they will be of the form

```
person.required 

person.invalid
```

or something similar

They act as kind of namespaces